# Div not submitting form

Tags: javascript, html

i've tried a lot of different methods to get this done, however none actually worked any suggestions? Thanks

```
<div name="login" class="blue_button" onclick="
document.getElementById("form").submit();"><div class="blue_button_text noselect">Login</div></div>
```

Comment: Why are you using a div as a button? That's an accessibility fail in that keyboard-only users can't use your page. Anyway, can you please show the html for your form?

Comment: @nnnnnn because otherwise my button won't look at good, the text will change location on the button and it's annoying. why do you want to see my form?

Comment: I wanted to see your form because I wondered if there was a problem with it. I've since realised that wasn't an issue and posted an answer. Regarding the button not looking good and being "annoying", it will be even more annoying to people who aren't physically capable of using a mouse or other pointing device. If you feel you *must* do this then please add a `tabindex` attribute to the div and a key event handler to make it behave like a real button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you've declared the form with the `<form>` tag? Also, try to change the tag of the submit button from `<div>` to `<button>` or `<input>`. Makes more sense semantically.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've tried to use double-quote characters for your element attributes *and* for the string literal in your JS. So your `onclick` attribute is read as `onclick="document.getElementById("` with the `form").submit();"` part left over.

Change the inner double-quote characters to single-quote characters and it will work (assuming you have a form with `id="form"`):

```
onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit();"
```

Comment: Then there must be some other problem with code not shown. Your form *does* have `id="form"`, yes?. The code that you have shown will work if you fix the quotes, as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/ju8r6ptj/

Comment: Yup it's got that, weird is there away i can do this with CSS?

Comment: Or make it so that my div doesn't change when i class it as a button

Comment: Basically when it's a button the text will change its size and float

Comment: You *can* style a `<button>` element with CSS, but there's no reason why your existing code shouldn't work once you fix the quotes. Did you see it working in the fiddle I provided?